# Best way to mock and unit test this method which has static builders

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the following private function that I need to test (simplified for this question):

```
private AmazonS3 getAmazonS3Client(boolean supportsEncryption) {

    AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    if (supportsEncryption) {
        amazonS3 = AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(...)
                .withCredentials(...))
                .withEncryptionMaterials(...)
                .build();
    } else {
        amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(...)
                .withCredentials(...)
                .build();
    }

    return amazonS3;
}
```

I am calling this function from another public function where the value of supportsEncryption is passed.

**How can I mock these static builder methods, so that I can test whether this branched code works correctly or not?
Alternatively what would be a good way to organize this code to make it easier to test?**

Comment: encapsulate those static implementation concerns behind abstractions that can be mocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate those static implementation concerns behind abstractions that can be mocked.

```
public interface AmazonS3ClientBuilderService  {
    AmazonS3 buildClient();
    AmazonS3 buildEncryptedClient();
}
```

The implementation of this interface will wrap the static builder methods

```
public class DefaultAmazonS3ClientBuilderService implements AmazonS3ClientBuilderService {
    public AmazonS3 buildClient() {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(...)
            .withCredentials(...)
            .build();
    }
    public AmazonS3 buildEncryptedClient() {
        return AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(...)
            .withCredentials(...))
            .withEncryptionMaterials(...)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Refactor target code you depend on the abstraction rather than the concretion

```
private AmazonS3ClientBuilderService clientBuilder; // To be populated via injection.
private AmazonS3 getAmazonS3Client(boolean supportsEncryption) {
    AmazonS3 amazonS3;
    if (supportsEncryption) {
        amazonS3 = clientBuilder.buildEncryptedClient();
    } else {
        amazonS3 = clientBuilder.buildClient();
    }
    return amazonS3;
}
```

The target class should follow explicit dependency principle via constructor injection. This will allow abstractions to be replaced when testing in isolation, either via custom implementations or mocking frameworks.

Comment: now how do you test `DefaultAmazonS3ClientBuilderService` ?